# Link formatting bug in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks

Trying to add some related links in a question using

`Related:`**`[Is there still a place for MDI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486020/is-there-still-a-place-for-mdi "Is there still a place for MDI?")`**`[Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463221/delphi-mdi-vs-tabs-for-multi-document-interface "Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface")`

[resulted in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/33079#33079)

`<div>Related:`**`<a title='Is there still a place for MDI?") [Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface](`**`<a href=' rel="nofollow" delphi-mdi-vs-tabs-for-multi-document-interface="" 1463221="" questions="" stackoverflow.com="" http:="" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486020/is-there-still-a-place-for-mdi">stackoverflow.com/questions/1463221/…</a> "Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface">Is there still a place for MDI?`

Whereas

`Related:`**`[Is there still a place for MDI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486020/is-there-still-a-place-for-mdi)`**`[Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463221/delphi-mdi-vs-tabs-for-multi-document-interface "Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface")`

worked as expected

`<div>Related:`**`<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486020/is-there-still-a-place-for-mdi">Is there still a place for MDI?</a>`**`<a title="Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463221/delphi-mdi-vs-tabs-for-multi-document-interface">Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface</a>`

It get's even hairier if you do it

`Related:[Is there still a place for MDI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486020/is-there-still-a-place-for-mdi "Is there still a place for MDI?")[Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463221/delphi-mdi-vs-tabs-for-multi-document-interface "Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface")` (no spaces)

Comment: Related: [Is there still a place for MDI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486020/is-there-still-a-place-for-mdi "Is there still a place for MDI?") [Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463221/delphi-mdi-vs-tabs-for-multi-document-interface "Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface")

Comment: Related: [Is there still a place for MDI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486020/is-there-still-a-place-for-mdi) [Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463221/delphi-mdi-vs-tabs-for-multi-document-interface "Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface")

Comment: Related:[Is there still a place for MDI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486020/is-there-still-a-place-for-mdi "Is there still a place for MDI?") [Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463221/delphi-mdi-vs-tabs-for-multi-document-interface "Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface")

Comment: [I know I like these titles](http://example.com/ "and often hide easter eggs in them.")

Comment: @The [Cat](http://there.is.not "harm") [done](http://with.people "knowing") [what](http://i.wanted.to "link").

Comment: talking about breaking stuff `@The [Cat](http://there.is.not "harm") [done](http://with.people "knowing") [what](http://i.wanted.to "link").`

Comment: Related: [Is there still a place for MDI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486020/is-there-still-a-place-for-mdi "Is there still a place for MDI?")[Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463221/delphi-mdi-vs-tabs-for-multi-document-interface "Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface")

Comment: Related:[Is there still a place for MDI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486020/is-there-still-a-place-for-mdi "Is there still a place for MDI?") [Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463221/delphi-mdi-vs-tabs-for-multi-document-interface "Delphi, MDI vs Tabs for multi-document interface")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

greedy vs. non-greedy matching issue, fixed once I deploy in ~12 hours.